# Computer security - videos or podcasts recommendations

Tags: security, podcast

I am looking for podcasts or videos on computer security. Ideally they should cover the basics and the more advanced topics.

So the best one I have found is [security now](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) by Steve Gibson and Leo Laporte other there any other good ones?

Comment: +1 for Security Now .. very informative and interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I like Security Now, and I used to listen another podcast called [PaulDotCom Security Weekly](http://pauldotcom.com/). It's more geared to people who work in the computer security field than people who are simply interested in computer security, which is why I stopped listening to it.

Security-wise, they really know their stuff.

Comment: +1 They are a different group of guys, that's for sure.  But their shows always have a lot of great information.

Answer (score 2):

For network security and compliance issues check out [RISKY.BIZ](http://risky.biz/) and their podcasts [Risky Business](http://risky.biz/netcasts/risky-business) and the interview/event feed, [RB2](http://risky.biz/netcasts/rb2).

Answer (score 0):

There are two podcast questions in ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/search?q=podcast

I know you specified 'Security', but I believe a bunch of the answers in those posts include this.

Answer (score 0):

it's not typical training but anyway really worth watching and eye opening:

[chaos communication congress](http://www.ccc.de/congress/) - take a look at conference recording.

start with this - [not only] about dns: dan kaminsky - [22C3: Black Ops Of TCP/IP](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=6308488589809281787&)